# Google colab stops working and got disconnected

Tags: google-colaboratory

while training my model google colab stops working and kernel got disconnected. What can I do to restart and continue my training ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab notebooks have an idle timeout of 90 minutes and absolute timeout of 12 hours. This means, if user does not interact with his Google Colab notebook for more than 90 minutes, its instance is automatically terminated. Also, maximum lifetime of a Colab instance is 12 hours.

The one of the easiest method to prevent it from disconnecting is you can insert one more cell to the below and type

```
while True:pass
```

There are another methods to do that as well, one of these is:
You can basically open the console prompt and type

```
    function ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Connect pushed"); 
    document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}

    setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);
```

this is a js code which clicks on the connect button every 60 seconds to keep your session alive.

For long training files I recommend you to use GPU and local runtimes.